# Check-out broken after theme installation

Tags: magento2, checkout, javascript, theme

I've installed a theme and everything works as intended except the check-out page, it seems like a JS file is missing or something. Any ideas what's going wrong?

- Magento v2.1.7
- Nothing in logs or browser console

[image: Broken]

[image: Working]

Answer (score 0):

It ended up being the fact that buying a configurable product (virtual product without weight in cart) will remove the "Shipping" page. Changing the virtual products to "This product has weight" resolved the issue.